# How can I sudo without a terminal?

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome-terminal

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.  I tried to install python3.8 and set it as the default python3 installation using `update-alternatives`.  I know that doing so breaks terminal, so I edited `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` to change the shebang to `/usr/bin/python3.6`.  However, in my haste I made a typo and set it to `/usr/bin/python3.8`.  So now I can't open my terminal, and since I can't open my terminal I can't sudo to set it back to 3.6.  Somehow I need to run a text editor with sudo privileges, but without the luxury of a terminal.  Or I need to open some terminal that *isnt* `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal`.

I've tried opening a file in gedit and calling it `terminal.sh` and putting the contents as `/usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal`, but double clicking it in File Explorer doesn't actually run it, even after setting permissions to executable.  So I'm stumped.

Comment: You want a tty. `Ctrl-Alt-F[1-6]` will bring one up. I can't recall which one is the GUI and whether F1 will bring you to the login screen on Ubuntu 18.04, but at least F3-F5 should bring up a non-GUI tty

Comment: Also, you shouldn't mess with the system installation(s) of python. More stuff than your terminal depends on it.